# SharePoint 2013 crawling documents

Tags: 2013, content, content-enrichment

I'm in the process of writing a custom solution to parse xml that will be crawled from a file share. The plan is to use the Content Enrichment web service callout to parse the xml into individual managed properties for search purposes. In some cases the xml document contains a reference to a document hosted on another site. This document needs to be indexed as a managed property and searchable. Is this possible using CEWS? If not could I get some recommendations on how to implement this in Sharepoint (if possible)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to SP.SE.

I would use a custom connector for this (scales better than a webservice) - read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556429.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info. So using CEWS would be a performance bottleneck? The BCS connector looks promising especially the StreamAccessor operation.

Comment: Cews can be a perf. issue, right.